# How to reverse particular word in a string?

Tags: python

How to reverse a particular word in a string?

Comment: What does this have to do with pandas?

Comment: To reverse a string you can use `my_str = "DAWN"` then `print(my_str[::-1])`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using `string[::-1]`

Here is a one liner for that:

```
' '.join([word[::-1] if len(word) > 3 else word for word in sentence.split(' ')])
```

Comment: While it's good that you know how to solve the problem, it's expected on Stack Overflow not to give direct answers to trivial or homework questions, and especially not without any explanation. Please see [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).